# can anyone tell me the what could be the possible cause of SIGILL(4) (illegal instruction)in my code

Tags: c++, crash, client-server

```
MessageServer :: receiveMessage(Message **ppObj)
{
    *ppObj = 0;
    ((InputStream *)pInputStream)->reset();

    RESULT retVal = RESULT_E_FAIL;
    Message *pCurrentMessage = 0;
    MessageHeader *pCurrentHeader = 0;

    // Check for any pending messages to be committed to the application  
    {
        TUINT32 pendAddr, pendPort;

        pCurrentMessage = pSequencer->getPending(pInputStream, pendAddr, pendPort);
        if ( pCurrentMessage )
        {
            //printf("Got pending...\n");

            // update the input stream with the pended msg's <addr, port>
            pInputStream->setRemoteAddress(DefaultSocketAddress(pendAddr, pendPort));

            *ppObj = pCurrentMessage;
            return MESSAGE_S_ACCEPTED;
        }
    }

    pCurrentHeader = pHeaderParser->createHeader();

    CAPTURE_RUN_END;
    CAPTURE_WAIT_START;
    RESULT result = pCurrentHeader->deserialize(*pInputStream);
    CAPTURE_WAIT_END;
    CAPTURE_RUN_START;

#if defined VXWORKS

    // Start capture here since this is the recv point
    StopwatchUsec stopwatch;
    stopwatch.start();
#endif 

    if ( result != RESULT_S_OK )
    {
        SocketAddress *pLocalAddress = pInputStream->localAddress();

          // LOG(FacilityIDMessage, 
          //   MessageLogAttr::MESSAGE_SERVER_MSG_NOT_RCVD_LOG_ID, 
          //  pMSLoggingString, 
          //  pLocalAddress->address(),
          //  pLocalAddress->portNum(),
          //  result);

        // check if error occured because initialization did not succeed.
        // If so, try to reinitialize
        if (!(((InputStream *)pInputStream)->isOpen())) {
            pInputStream->close();
            pInputStream->bind(*pLocalAddress);
            TBOOLEAN reinitSuccess = ((InputStream *)pInputStream)->isOpen();
            if (debugMS) {
                printf("%s: reinitialization %s\n", getName(), 
                        (reinitSuccess ? "succeeded" : "failed"));
            }
        }

        // process error here
        pCurrentHeader->releaseHeader();
        return result;
    }

    SocketAddress *pRemoteAddress = pInputStream->remoteAddress();
    SocketAddress *pLocalAddress = pInputStream->localAddress();


    TUINT32 remoteAddr = ntohl(pRemoteAddress->address());
    TUINT32 remotePort = (TUINT32)ntohs(pRemoteAddress->portNum());
    TUINT32 localAddr = ntohl(pLocalAddress->address());
    TUINT32 localPort = (TUINT32)ntohs(pLocalAddress->portNum());

    //printf("Msg rcvd at <localAddr=0x%x, localPort=%d>  <remoteAddr=0x%x, remotePort=%d>\n", 
         //   localAddr, localPort, remoteAddr, remotePort);

    LOG(FacilityIDMessage, 
        MessageLogAttr::MESSAGE_SERVER_MSG_RCVD_LOG_ID, 
        pMSLoggingString,
        pCurrentHeader->type(),
        pCurrentHeader->sequenceNumber(),
        remoteAddr,
        remotePort,
        localAddr,
        localPort);

    pCurrentMessage = pCurrentHeader->createMessage();

    if ( !pCurrentMessage )
    {
        MessageDB db;

        pCurrentMessage = db.create(pCurrentHeader->type(), localPort);

        // If the above fails and this server can run any message try to create.
        if ( (!pCurrentMessage) && (processAny == TRUE) )
        {
            pCurrentMessage = db.create(pCurrentHeader->type(), 0);
        }
    }

    if ( pCurrentMessage )
    {
        pCurrentMessage->increment();

        pCurrentMessage->receiveHeader(*pCurrentHeader);

        retVal = pCurrentMessage->deserialize(*pInputStream);

        LOG(FacilityIDMessage, 
            MessageLogAttr::MESSAGE_SERVER_MSG_DESERIALIZE_LOG_ID, 
            pMSLoggingString, 
            pCurrentMessage->getTypeName(),
            pCurrentMessage->getType(),
            pCurrentMessage->getIndex(),
            remoteAddr,
            remotePort,
            localAddr,
            localPort);

        numRcvd++;

        if ( retVal != RESULT_E_FAIL )
        {
            retVal = MESSAGE_S_ACCEPTED;

            // If reply, do not send to avoid looping`enter code here`
            if ( !pCurrentMessage->isReply() )
            {
                // Accept message?
                retVal = pSequencer->accept(pCurrentMessage,
                                            remoteAddr,
                                            remotePort,
                                            pInputStream); 

            }
        }

        *ppObj = pCurrentMessage;

#if defined VXWORKS
        TUINT32 delta = stopwatch.readUsecs();
        if ( delta > maxRecvTime )
        {
            maxRecvTime = delta;
        }

        if ( delta < minRecvTime )
        {
            minRecvTime = delta;
        }

        totalRecvTime += delta;
#endif 
    }
    else
    {
        LOG(FacilityIDMessage, 
            MessageLogAttr::MESSAGE_SERVER_MSG_NOT_CREATED_LOG_ID, 
            pMSLoggingString, 
            pCurrentHeader->type(),
            pCurrentHeader->sequenceNumber(),
            remoteAddr,
            remotePort,
            localAddr,
            localPort);

        pCurrentHeader->releaseHeader();
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

I attached the core files in GDB and got to know that this crash is happening at (retVal = MESSAGE_S_ACCEPTED) this point when i am trying to assign some value into unsigned integer . how can this happen . can anyone help in this ?

Comment: a simple mov isn't really a reason for an SIGILL. usually this is when you overwrite your program memory with data, or when you call al libary that's not loaded or stuff like that.

Have you tried stuff like moving the "retVal = MESSAGE_S_ACCEPTED; " into an else-part of ( "if !pCurrentMEssage->isReply())" ? 

what environment do you build for? Emulators sometimes have strange behaviours :P

Comment: Can I ask why you've created a new scope at "// Check for any pending messages to be committed to the application"? I'm not sure that it has anything to do with your problem, but perhaps there is some unintended effect. As far as debugging the issue, what is the value of retVal before you attempt to reassign it to MESSAGE_S_ACCEPTED?